# ProxySQL connections more than configured to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, proxysql

We deployed one service on ProxySQL Cluster (3 nodes proxy cluster) for MySQL Database 5.7.
ProxySQL Version - proxysql-2.3.2-1
The service is using Hikari Pool.

The maximumPoolSize is configured to 30.

At proxysql level, the user configured for the service in mysql_users has max_connections to 1500 and in mysql_servers, max_connections is set to 8000.

When I see processlist on MySQL Database, I see 185 connections.

When the maximumPoolSize at application is set to 30, how it is opening 185 connections to the database?

Please let me know what information I need to provide to understand this behaviour. I am not very experienced on ProxySQL.

Please help me understand.